# How does Java JNI interact with Kotlin/Native to find object values?

Tags: object, java-native-interface, kotlin, native

From JetBrains  site :

> Kotlin/Native is a technology for compiling Kotlin to native binaries that run without any VM.

But how does Kotlin interact with JNI , in my knowledge if a C/C++ program using JNI wants to access a java field it has to use the `GetFieldID` function, but the C program needs information from the JVM describing the object and its value.

How does kotlin/Native resolve the value of fields, if Kotlin makes programs that doesn't depend on the VM how can it get the value of Java fields?

Answer (score 2):

## What is Kotlin native

Kotlin/Native does not do the same thing as JNI, the site describes Kotlin/Native like this...

> Kotlin/Native is a technology for compiling Kotlin to native binaries that run without any VM. It comprises a LLVM-based backend for the Kotlin compiler and a native implementation of the Kotlin runtime library. Kotlin/Native is primarily designed to allow compilation for platforms where virtual machines are not desirable or possible (such as iOS, embedded targets), or where a developer needs to produce a reasonably-sized self-contained program that does not require an additional runtime.
>   [[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native-overview.html)]

JNI lets Java code talk to native code, whereas Kotlin/Native allows you to compile Kotlin code into a native executable that does not require a JVM to run.

Comment: my question was not about the difference between JNI and kotlin/native but about how kotlin/native meant to replace jni , for exemple in .net native to replace P/invoke calls the compiler load the dll containing the unmanaged code after this he emit the code in the final execuatable ,is it the same processus for kotlin/native .

Comment: Kotlin native doesn't do the same thing as JNI, so it doesn't need to deal with native calls

Comment: if it doesn't ho will do it, we both now that kotline is built under the java byte code and java byte code have to call native code using jni for doing a lot of things

Comment: Kotlin/Native does not compile to java byte code, and it can run outside the JVM, so JNI would not be accessible

Comment: ok it 's true from the kotline site : Note that we do not intend to make arbitrary Kotlin/JVM programs runnable on Kotlin/Native or Kotlin/JS. It would be equivalent to implementing another JVM, which is both a lot of work and a lot of limitations for the runtime. We are going another way: providing a common language for all platforms while enabling creation of common libraries through seamless interoperability with platform code. thanks man.